# Different table declarations

Tags: t-sql

So this question has probably been asked before but I don't really know what to search for.

Any how. I would like to define my tables like this eg.:

```
[city]-[propertyID]-[value]
```

I think it's easy to maintain and the only problem is when I want to list every property for a city on one row. But the pivot function can neatly handle that. 
I believe that I can add new properties without redesigning the table.

What are the cons to this design?

Instead of designing the table like the folowing:

```
[city]-[propertyID1]-[propertyID2]-[propertyID3]-[propertyID4]
```

Comment: [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). Has a *few* places where its useful (sparse models) but in most cases more hassle than it's worth. E.g. how do you validate that `propertyID3` should be an integer between 0 and 100, `propertyID4` should be a string, `propertyID2` should be a foreign key relating to another table, etc.

Comment: thx. this seems to be the answer. can't mark this as the solution but i gave you a vote at least : )